# Why Theorem 71.1 in 《Topology》 of Munkres using points different from the common point

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, free-groups

As said in the title, the proof provided in the textbook is as followed:
[image: proof]
for each S it choose a point different from p. Why not use directly the common point as the intersection space in the proof? It seems much easier to argue in this way. To be clear, I thought an easier proof should be:
[image: proof1]

Comment: don't you need open sets to use Seifert-vanKampen?

Comment: @Mihail oh i did not notice this premise. Its role in the proof of Seifert-van Kampen seems to be very subtle. I will check the proofs again. Thank you